# Block the possibility of removal if the model has a foreign key

Tags: php, foreign-keys, yii2, relationship

Hi I have model with relation to himself. My relation i can show on this table:
[image]

This

> Rel_Category

is the same that this

> Id

.This is the table of category and subcategory. I want to block the possibility of removal if the model has a foreign key. And throw some exception or flash when user want to delete category where it foreign_key in Rel_Category. So if user want to delete test with id=54 then it should display some error that this category have a subcategory and user should first delete this subcategory(id=51 and id=53). 
 UPDATE: 
In my database i have no action on delete and update
[image]

Comment: You should do this in your table definition and not via PHP.

Comment: It impossible to write some 'if'? I tried to do if Rel_Category !=Null then delete but i dont know what to do next

Comment: You can do this via PHP, but you shouldn't since you'll encounter transactional and/or concurrency issues. Say you've checked that a category is not empty and are about to delete it. Between you checking and you deleting a parallel request has made the category empty. How can you handle that?

Comment: Can u show me any steps or something how can i do it in database? I work on Workbench i understand i should this in this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this in your database, and you could try this in your controller :

```
if (count($model->smCategories)) {
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', 'This category has sub categories and cannot be deleted.');
} else {
    $model->delete();
}
```

Comment: thanks it works :) whan You mean handle this in my database? Is there any steps in Yii2 doc how to do taht? I Work in workbench so there i should do some?

Answer (score 0):

You should define such constraints when you create your database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Category` (         
    ...

    CONSTRAINT `SelfReference` FOREIGN KEY (`Rel_Category`) REFERENCES `Category` (`Id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ....
);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

The idea here is that MySQL will maintain your data integrity constraints.

Comment: @qwerty On delete needs to be `RESTRICT`

Comment: ok thanks when i used restrict there is more chance to escape error when i deleted?:)

Comment: becouse on this page i can read: For an ON DELETE or ON UPDATE that is not specified, the default action is always RESTRICT.